# vkCmdWriteTimestamp writes the same time before and after the draw calls

Tags: c++, timer, timestamp, gpu, vulkan

I am trying to have a measure of how much it takes for a frame to render in my Vulkan application. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67358235/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-vulkan-pipeline) and [this](https://nikitablack.github.io/post/how_to_use_vulkan_timestamp_queries/) very helpful articles, but I think my code is not writing the timestamps appropriately. The issue is that when I read them, the time before and after the frame is always the same.

I am using multiple frames in flight, so multiple command buffers recorded, and `current` indicates the command buffer being recorded now. Here is the command buffer:

```
vkBeginCommandBuffer(cmd, ...);

vkCmdResetQueryPool(cmd, query_pool, current * 2, 2);
vkCmdWriteTimestamp(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, query_pool, current * 2);

vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cmd, ...);
// Draw commands...
vkCmdEndRenderPass(cmd);

vkCmdWriteTimestamp(cmd, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, query_pool, current * 2 + 1);
vkEndCommandBuffer(cmd);
```

I tried multiple ways of querying the result, from `vkGetQueryPoolResults` to `vkCmdCopyQueryPoolResults` with a buffer, but both give the same results so I assume the issue is with writing the timestamps. Here is an example of `vkGetQueryPoolResults`, which is called before the same command buffer is recorded and submitted again, so that queries have time to complete:

```
ui64 queries[4];
VkResult result = vkGetQueryPoolResults(device, query_pool, 2 * current, 2, 4 * sizeof(ui64), queries, 2 * sizeof(ui64), VK_QUERY_RESULT_64_BIT | VK_QUERY_RESULT_WITH_AVAILABILITY_BIT);
    
if (result == VK_NOT_READY)
    log::info("Result not ready");
else if (result == VK_SUCCESS)
    log::info("Current: %d, %d %d (Availability: %d %d)", current, queries[0], queries[2], queries[1], queries[3]);
```

I have also tried with different flags, including `VK_QUERY_RESULT_WITH_AVAILABILITY_BIT` and `VK_QUERY_RESULT_WITH_WAIT_BIT`. The results are as follow:

```
[ INFO ] Current: 0, 1421658976 1421658976 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 1, 1425976254 1425976254 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 2, 1438268198 1438268198 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 0, 1442609892 1442609892 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 1, 1454983477 1454983477 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 2, 1459295156 1459295156 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 0, 1471665161 1471665161 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 1, 1475966118 1475966118 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 2, 1488409009 1488409009 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 0, 1492655837 1492655837 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 1, 1504988977 1504988977 (Availability: 1 1)
[ INFO ] Current: 2, 1509278297 1509278297 (Availability: 1 1)
```

As you can see, even if the timestamps change from one frame to the next, the two timestamps recorded in the same frame are always the same, which seems like it took no time to execute the draw calls. I am probably missing something trivial in writing the timestamps, but I've tried many things and always get the same. Also, I didn't mention it before but I already checked for the device to support timestamps with `timestampValidBits` and got the timestamp period, that in my device is `1`.

Comment: I'm getting your exact same issue, have you managed to solve?

Comment: I finally managed to solve my issue, it was because I was multiplying the returned uint64_t values times the timestampPeriod float (which for my machine is 1). And the values were out of float precision they returned the same exact value.

Comment: Still, it seemingly isn't your issue...

Comment: So glad you could resolve your issue! I've been tinkering a bit more with the code lately and it still has the same problem, but I've come to think that it is because my integrated GPU doesn't support Metal Timestamps through [MoltenVK](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/MoltenVK/pull/1404), but for some reason it tries to take them anyways. I am still trying to get another computer to try it on, will keep you updated.